# Export nested hash table to csv in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, nested, export, hashtable

I have an array, with a nested hashtable containing data:

```
tid              : 1
token            : 12345
participant_info : @{firstname=bob; lastname=smith; email=bob.smith@email.com}
completed        : y

tid              : 2
token            : 67890
participant_info : @{firstname=Alice; lastname=Jones; email=alice.jones@email.com}
completed        : n
```

I would like to output this as a CSV with the nested items of firstname, surname and email pulled out of the inner hashtable - eg

```
tid,token,firstname,surname,email,completed
1,12345,bob,smith,bob.smith@email.com,y
2,67890,alice,jones,alice.jones@email.com,n
```

I'm going to guess that the answer is looping through with foreach and creating a custom ps object, but because my nested items aren't named, I can't work out how to do this using the other examples on here.

Any assistance is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and explain how it has not worked for you.

Comment: That isn't a valid hashtable.. You don't have any keys, just values.

Comment: Your outer hash does not appear to have key-value pairs? Also, how is this data generated? If you control that I would say your best bet is to put it into a better data structure to begin with.

Comment: Your hashtable also has an opening `@(` but no corresponding closing `)`.

Comment: The data is coming from Limesurvey's remote control API, using the list_participants method. I convert the received JSON using ConvertFrom-Json.

I have just noticed that the returned type is actually an array, which does include the inner hash table - I'm thinking I need to delete this one and ask again! :-)

Comment: edited to reflect that it's an array, but the core of what I'm trying to achieve is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your sample:

```
@(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        tid = 1
        token = 12345
        participant_info = @{
            firstname = 'bob'
            lastname = 'smith'
            email = 'bob.smith@email.com'
        }
        completed = 'N'
    }

    ...
)
```

And desired output:

```
id,token,firstname,surname,email,completed
1,12345,bob,smith,bob.smith@email.com,y
2,67890,alice,jones,alice.jones@email.com,n
```

You can do something like this:

```
$JsonList = @( ... )
$Path = "$Env:UserProfile\file.csv"

ForEach ($Sample in $JsonList)
{
    $Sample | Select-Object -Property @(
        @{N = 'id';        E = { $Sample.tid }}
        @{N = 'token';     E = { $Sample.token }}
        @{N = 'firstname'; E = { $Sample.participant_info.firstname }}
        @{N = 'surname';   E = { $Sample.participant_info.lastname }}
        @{N = 'email';     E = { $Sample.participant_info.email }}
        @{N = 'completed'; E = { $Sample.completed }}
    ) | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Append
}
```

---

Edit: you're dealing with `PSCustomObject`, not `Hashtable`, so my previous syntax won't work for that.  Here's what I'm presuming your code to look like now (I've updated my above example):

```
@"
[
    {
        "tid": 1,
        "token": 12345,
        "participant_info": {
            "firstname": "bob",
            "lastname": "smith",
            "email": "bob.smith@email.com"
        },
        "completed": "N"
    }

    ...
]
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: @DavidPhillips Update your question with `$Json | Format-List -Property *` output

Comment: Thanks for the time you've spent on this. It does appear that something is a bit odd as the code you've given didn't output the answer I was expecting. If I just type the variable into the shell, I get a table of `1 123456 @{firstname=bob;surname=smith;email=bob.smith@email.com} Y` If I do a `foreach $item in $sample`, then `write-host ($item[0])`, I get `@{id=1;token=12345;participant_info=;completed=N}`. No matter what I try, I can't return the inner values from here - eg `$sample[0]['id']`

Comment: Thanks! But this returns no data for each attribute - the CSV shows multiple rows, but with no data. 

`$jsonlist.tid` lists all of the tid's, and `$jsonlist.tid.getvalue(0)` returns the correct value, but I've not been able to use the square bracket notation to return anything.

Comment: @DavidPhillips Check my edit.  I've updated to your use-case.

Comment: Boom! Perfect - thank you so much for helping and staying with my badly worded question. I've kept the other version for hashtables incase I should encounter those in the future. I thought anything with {} brackets rather than () was a hashtable.

Comment: @DavidPhillips Glad to help.  Kindly mark this as the answer with the green checkmark since it fixed your problem.  `@( )` is the powershell array syntax and `@{ }` can be a number of things that use the key:value structure (ordered dictionary, pscustomobject, hashtable, lists, etc.)  And in fact, `{ }` on their own indicate a scriptblock.

Comment: Done - sorry - I'd looked to do that, then got distracted! 

And now I see why I couldn't get it to work - I hadn't realised I needed to address the items in the participants_info field in the same way as the others - going back to the original question - my nested items _were_ named - they were participants_info. 

Every day is a learning day!